# How to start workflow 2013 from powershell

Tags: sharepoint-workflow

There are some guides on [how to work with 2010 workflows using powershell](http://www.mysharepointadventures.com/2012/06/start-a-workflow-using-powershell/).  Can somebody point out to me how to do the same with 2013 workflows? They are no longer listed inside `$list.WorkFlowAssociations`.

Answer (score 4):

```
$siteURL = "URL"
$web = Get-SPWeb $siteURL
$wfm = New-object Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager($web)
$sub = $wfm.GetWorkflowSubscriptionService()
$subscriptions = $sub.EnumerateSubscriptionsByList($list.ID)
```

Inside $subscriptions, there are associated workflow. Hope it helps

Comment: see http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.com/2013/05/programmatically-start-sharepoint-2013.html for detailed information

Answer (score 4):

This [MSDN blog post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23850.sharepoint-2013-workflow-management-starting-a-workflow-using-powershell.aspx) shows most of the answer but they were trying to iterate over the list instead of the items in the list.  Below is an updated version.

```
$sourceWebURL = '<URL>'
$sourceListName = '<List Name>'
$TargetWorkflow = '<Workflow Name>'
$spSourceWeb = Get-SPWeb $sourceWebURL
$spSourceList = $spSourceWeb.Lists[$sourceListName]
$items = $spSourceList.getItems()

#-- Getting a Workflow manager object to work with.
$wfm = New-object Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager($spSourceweb)
#-- Getting the subscriptions
$sub = $wfm.GetWorkflowSubscriptionService()
#-- Getting the specific workflow within the list of subscriptions on the specific list. (SP2010 associated workflows basically)
$WF = $sub.EnumerateSubscriptionsByList($spSourcelist.ID) | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "$TargetWorkflow"}
#-- Getting a Workflow instance in order to perform my commands.
$wfis=$wfm.GetWorkflowInstanceService()

Foreach($item in $items){
    #-- Creating the dictionary object I need to parse into StartWorkflow. This could be most other workflow commands.
    $object = New-Object 'system.collections.generic.dictionary[string,object]'
    $object.Add("WorkflowStart", "StartWorkflow");
    $wfis.StartWorkflowOnListItem($WF, $item.ID, $object)
}
```